# Transgression: Usage

Tags: grammar

is the following statement grammatically correct?

"That picture causes me several transgressions"
I know it is not, but cannot explain why.

Comment: What do you think transgression means? What do you mean to communicate when you say that something causes you transgressions? What have you done by way of looking in dictionaries and thesauruses to help you work out the problem? Why do you think this is a grammar, rather than a word choice or vocabulary issue?

Answer (score 1):

"I know it is not, but cannot explain why."

Then you do not "know" after all.

Grammatically the sentence in question is fine.  Semantically - well, it doesn't makes much sense.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, I think I can see from your profile that you haven't yet taken the introductory [tour]. I'd encourage you to do this and especially look at the advice on how to write good answers. The specific question what whether the usage was grammatically correct, you have said it is, but you haven't explained why, or what the semantic problem is. We look for answers which will be helpful to others besides the OP, so they should be detailed and explain reasons for their assertions.

Answer (score 0):

"Transgression" means "the act of crossing the line"

> [**Transgression**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transgression)
>
> An act that goes against a law, rule, or code of conduct; an offence.
>
> *‘I'll be keeping an eye out for further transgressions’*
>   *‘few ministers now stand down because of sexual transgressions’*
>   *(mass noun) ‘her transgression of genteel etiquette’*

---

> That picture causes me several transgressions.

Semantically, a picture cannot cause you to **act**. It can make you **feel** something, and that feeling (not the picture) can then be the cause for you to commit transgressions.

Also, it is not "the picture" that causes it, but rather "seeing the picture".
*Unless you mean that the picture is cursed and its existence changes your behavior, regardless of whether you see it or not. But I'm going to assume that that's not what you mean.*

I would at the very least rephrase this as

> Seeing that picture causes me to commit several transgressions.

However, I still don't like using "transgression" here. It feels out of place. Some alternatives:

> - Seeing that picture upsets me. I'm prone to misbehaving when I'm upset.
> - Seeing that picture makes me so upset that I start making mistakes.
> - Seeing that picture puts me in a foul mood.
> - I can't handle seeing that picture.

I know that I've taken some liberties with the actual message that you're trying to convey, but these alternatives seems to flow nicer and avoid weird implications about the cause and effect of seeing a picture.